# how to change input_length in TensorFlow embedding layer？

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, embedding

My first layer is embedding layer. Most embedding layer has fixed input_length, eg: max length of sentence, like this(https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/sequences/word_embeddings):

```
embedding_dim=16

model = tf.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen)
y=model(x)
```

But lengths of sentences in my dataset are different, I want to change input_length of embedding every sentence, how to change model? how to call it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the input_length parameter for every sentence, what you should do is define a `MAXIMUM_SENTENCE_LENGTH` constant where you will pad all your sentences with the special value 0 if they are less than that maximum length, or simply cut off the excessive words if they surpass it.

You would then use the `mask_zero` parameter by setting it to True to simply mask out those excessive 0 tokens so that they wouldn't affect the outputs of the model or the gradients back-propagation during training.

Check this [tutorial](https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-iii-variable-length-sequences.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I want to ask why length of sentences must be same?Is it because the embedding itself or the following rnn layers?

Comment: Mainly it's because of the following rnn layers, you can't have an rnn trained for arbitrary sentences lengths.

Comment: If you intend to use only the embeddings layer, you could simply set the input_length to the length of the sentences in your batch, as long as they are the same across all sentences.

Comment: I fond one code in(https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/train.py). In line 86, you can see he used  sequence_length=x_train.shape[1],maybe it's one method to solve this problem, as good as yours.